# How to access object properties within an object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var app = {
    first_name: 'john',
    last_name: 'doe',
    full_name: this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name
};
```

How to access properties within an object? I am getting **undefined** using `this.property-name` as above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your full_name property a method

```
var app = {
        first_name: 'john',
        last_name: 'doe',
        full_name:function(){
            return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
        }
    };

    alert(app.full_name());
```

Cheers !!!

Comment: @zarpio-Tick my answer if it solves your problem.